# How to enable Swagger to listen to IP instead of localhost?

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-ui

I have Swagger integrated with my desktop application listening on port 8081 (http://localhost:8081).
Swagger-ui is available on http://localhost:8081/docs
You see here that its listening only on localhost.

How do I get the server to listen on the actual IP address of my Server e.g. 10.12.13.23 and not localhost?

As I want to access it from another PC and send and receive API responses, how do I configure to listen to IP address?

Comment: What programming language and framework do you use? E.g. Java+Springfox, or .NET+Swashbuckle, or Node.js +swagger-tools, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the spring.rest.hostname property in application.properties file

```
spring.rest.hostname=10.12.13.23
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

1. Go to the swagger folder
2. Open file named `package.json`
3. Replace `localhost:8081` with `{your_ip}:8081`
4. Restart swagger